# How can I use vim to remove first few characters of the selected lines using commands?

Tags: vim

How can I remove the first few characters like remove **;** from the selected lines using commands? I switched into the insert mode, but can't figure out how to do.

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_ftp.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
```

Answer (score 62):

1. Place cursor on first or last `;`
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to enter Visual Block mode
3. Use arrow keys or <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> to select the `;` characters you want to delete (or the other "*first few characters*")
4. Press <kbd>x</kbd> to delete them all at once

Comment: using `j` or `k` is better than arrow keys ;-)

Comment: VSCode's embedded terminal (on Windows using git bash), I had to use `Ctrl` + `Q` instead of `Ctrl` + `V` as it was bound to paste.

Answer (score 12):

Normally you'd do this in ex-mode, e.g., if that is the entire file you could do just

```
:%s/^;//
```

to remove all leading semicolons.

If there are other lines that you do not want to modify, of course, it becomes more complicated.

Comment: Can we give line numbers in the above %s command?

Comment: You could use line numbers instead of `%`.  That's a standard feature of ex/vi.

Answer (score 12):

techraf's answer worked for me. Another option is to use the :norm-command of vim.

1. Place cursor on first line
2. Press `Shift+V` to enter Visual Line mode
3. Press `16j` to select 16 lines below the current line
4. Type `:norm ^x`

`:` enters command mode, `norm` specifies a command that will be executed on all lines, `^` goes to the beginning of the line, and `x` deletes the first character.